# Dynamic .htaccess using the url name

Tags: .htaccess

In a page 
http://example.com/alum/ 
there is a link to the file 
http://example.com/1.pdf

But I want to redirect to alum.pdf,  using the url name in the name of the file

the same with /teac/ (for example) I want to redirec to to teac.pdf  not to 1.pdf

How can I do it?

thanks!

Comment: do you have say PHP installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is WordPress